# Ethminer Segmentation Fault

Tags: bug, ethminer, segfault

I'm having problems with ethminer on my system. Software works completely fine except the situation when I'm trying to run ethminer over SSH and I'm not "physically" logged in on that particular machine. On the other hand, when I log in and eventually log out - everything works great. What's wrong? I'm I missing something, or is it simply a bug?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS together with AMD cards.

I would appreciate any form of help.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add specific details of the commands that you have executed and the respective outputs?

Comment: ./ethminer -G -t 3 and output is simply: Segmentation fault (core dump).

Comment: Do you know how to use `gdb`? And did you compile `ethminer` from source? If yes/yes, you could compile ethminer with debug flags and attach it to gdb. If not, you could also load the `core dump` to gdb to figure out the reason. But it's most likely a bug in ethminer.

Answer (score 1):

See if the following works:

Here a script to start `ethminer` in the background. You should be able to run this script from your physical terminal or remotely over SSH.

Save the following text into `$HOME/bin/runEthminer`. You may have to run the command `mkdir $HOME/bin` first and you will have to customise your `ethminer` command line or the FARMURL environment variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE="$HOME/ethminer.log"

# Kill existing instance of ethminer
if [ "$(pidof ethminer)" ]
then
  echo "Killing ethminer"
  killall -q ethminer 
fi

# Farming to a local geth instance
FARMURL="http://192.168.1.123:8545"

# Farming to pool - check your pool URL specifications
# FARMURL="http://{poolurl}?/miner={youraddress}@{megahashes}

ethminer -F $FARMURL -G 2>> $LOGFILE &
```

Set the executable bit of this file by running the command `chmod 700 $HOME/bin/runEthminer`.

You can now start `ethminer` by running the command `runEthminer` or `$HOME/bin/runEthminer`.

You can view your `ethminer` log file using

```
tail -f $HOME/ethminer.log
```

Answer (score 1):

For me on Ubuntu 16.04 with AMD cards, I installed Ubuntu server, I did **NOT** install X on it, and I'm using [amdgpu-pro 16.30](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx) drivers.

ethminer works perfectly from a systemd recipe running as a non-root user.  I never have to login to the machine.

On Ubuntu 14.04 it is necessary to start X, and from ~/.xsession invoke ethminer (using fglrx), but this is not needed in 16.04 and might even cause problems.